# Starting with Head First Java

Tags: java, compilation

A while back I started to learn python coding and not long into it, I backed out. Getting some things together now I started with Head First Java book as my go-to intro to coding.

I did my first .java file with the below lines:

```
public class MyFirstApp {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println( “I Rule!" );
        System.out.println( “The World” );
    }

}
```

Going for the next step to compile this is what i get:

```
Mohameds-MBP:Desktop malsaman$ javac MyFirstApp.java
MyFirstApp.java:4: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        System.out.println( “I Rule!" );
                            ^
MyFirstApp.java:4: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println( “I Rule!" );
                                   ^
MyFirstApp.java:4: error: unclosed string literal
        System.out.println( “I Rule!" );
                                    ^
MyFirstApp.java:5: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        System.out.println( “The World” );
                            ^
MyFirstApp.java:5: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        System.out.println( “The World” );
                                  ^
5 errors
```

Obviously missing that step couldnt run the file.

Comment: Do not use typographic quote characters (`“` and `”`). Always use the straight typewriter quote (`"`).

Comment: Did you copy and paste? If you did, don't do it. Typing it will help your Java learning.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Replace quotes with straight ones `"` and it will compile. Also it worth using some [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) - it will highlight such mistakes instantly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I’ll look into the IDE for optimal use.